# java округление дробной части чила до четной цифры

Tags: java

Есть случайно генерируемое число, с двумя цифрами после запятой.

```
String part= new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format((Math.random() * (bS - aS) ) + aS);
```

Как сделать округление этого числа так, чтобы 2 цифра после запятой была бы четной?
То есть, если генерируется условно говоря, 14.33, как получить 14,32 или 14,34 ? не принципиально в какую сторону

Comment: Если случайное целое разделить на 50 будет то что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не критично, в какую сторону округлять, можно просто заменить последнюю нечетную цифру ближайшей чётной, при помощи [`Matcher::replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceFirst(java.util.function.Function)) / [`Matcher::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) в Java 9+:

```java
private static Pattern lastOdd = Pattern.compile("[13579]$");

public static String num(double aS, double bS) {
    String part = new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format((Math.random() * (bS - aS) ) + aS);
    
    System.out.print(part + " -> "); // отладочный вывод
    
    return lastOdd.matcher(part)
        .replaceFirst(mr -> String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(mr.group()) - 1));
}
```

Тест:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(num(5.0, 25.0));
}
```

```
6.33 -> 6.32
12.16 -> 12.16
15.13 -> 15.12
19.48 -> 19.48
11.35 -> 11.34
13.77 -> 13.76
7.89 -> 7.88
23.63 -> 23.62
19.48 -> 19.48
5.87 -> 5.86
```

---

Аналогично (и более эффективно) можно домножить случайное число на 100, округлить до целого, сбросить младший бит в 0 и разделить на 100.0:

```java
public static String num(double aS, double bS) {
    double v = (Math.random() * (bS - aS)) + aS;
    String part = new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(
        (Math.round(100 * v) & ~1L) / 100.0
    );
    
    System.out.printf("%.2f -> ", v);
    
    return part;
}
```

---

Еще один вариант (более случайный) без битовой операции, предложенный @Stanislav Volodarskiy:

```java
public static String num(double aS, double bS) {
    double v = (Math.random() * (bS - aS) ) + aS;
    String part = new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(
        (Math.round(50 * v)) / 50.0
    );
    
    System.out.printf("%.2f -> ", v);
    
    return part;
}
```

Однако здесь могут возникать округления в большую сторону

```
9.19 -> 9.20
14.09 -> 14.10
9.63 -> 9.62
11.45 -> 11.44
12.10 -> 12.10
15.53 -> 15.54
7.97 -> 7.96
18.40 -> 18.40
19.95 -> 19.94
20.09 -> 20.10
```

Comment: ОСпасибО! ТО что нужно как раз)

Comment: Регулярка и работа со строками необязательны, можно просто сбросить младший бит  -- строковый результат чуть сбил с толку в начале ответа :)

Comment: 100 -> 50 и убрать битовые операции.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да интересный вариант, при этом ещё и "рандомное" округление возникает